# Ext.Net - Change panel width from Javascript

Tags: ext.net

I would like to change panel width size from javascript.
Here my code but don't work:

**Javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ExtraExpandMAP = function (pannello) {
        pannello.setWidth = 920;
    };
</script>
```

**Asp.Net code:**

```
<ext:Panel ID="PanelLazyMAP" runat="server" 
    Region="East" 
    Width="460"                 
    Title="Mappa"
    Layout="Fit" 
    Floatable="false"
    Resizable="true"
    Collapsed="true"                    
    Collapsible="true"
    AutoScroll="false"
    BodyStyle="background-color:#ffffff;"
    MarginSpec="84 0 0 0" AnimCollapse ="false">
    <HeaderConfig>
        <Items>
            <ext:Button ID="btnExpandExtraMAP" runat="server" Icon="RewindGreen">
                <Listeners>
                    <Click Handler="ExtraExpandMAP(#{PanelLazyMAP});">              
                    </Click>
                </Listeners>
            </ext:Button>
        </Items>
    </HeaderConfig>
</ext:Panel>
```

Comment: Yes I Know.  In description I have indicate (Ext.Net)

Comment: "It doesn't work" is the most non-descriptive error description I have seen. We can help you faster if you provide additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:

```
pannello.setWidth = 920;
```

instead of:

```
pannello.setWidth(920);
```